# Joomla custom fields for category - subtitle & headerimage

Tags: joomla-3.x, custom-field, category-blog

I have an override for the category/blog.php layout and i want to display a headerimage and a subtitle with the custom fields introduced in joomla 3.7. For this implementation I already use Joomla 3.9.3.

I have already used custom fields in articles and it works fine, but not in categories.

To get this to work I limit this to the subtitle. On the screenshot you can see I added a custom field "subtitle" to Category and finally the input field for the subtitle will be placed only in categories (and not in articles).

[image]

I tried to display the custom field like the ones in my articles in the other override in category/blog_item.php (-> https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Adding_custom_fields/Overrides, Section "Loading individual fields")

```
<?php
    // File location: /templates/templatename/html/com_content/category/blog.php

    // loop first to make the fields easy to reference via the field name as a key
    foreach($this->item->jcfields as $jcfield):
        $this->item->customFields[$jcfield->name] = $jcfield;
    endforeach;

    echo $this->item->customFields['subtitle']->label;
    echo $this->item->customFields['subtitle']->name;
    echo $this->item->customFields['subtitle']->value;
    echo $this->item->customFields['subtitle']->rawvalue;
?>
```

I also tried it with this code and only the name and the label of the custom field "subtitle" is displayed:

```
<?php 
    foreach(FieldsHelper::getFields('com_content.categories', $child) as $field) :
         $child->customFields[$field->name] = $field;
    endforeach;

    echo $child->customFields['subtitle']->label;
    echo $child->customFields['subtitle']->name;
    echo $child->customFields['subtitle']->value;
    echo $child->customFields['subtitle']->rawvalue; 
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As a matter of best coding practices, please get in the habit of writing a single space before and after concatenating dots/commas.  One of these days, you might be banging your head against the wall wondering why your "clearly accessed object" isn't being accessed. https://stackoverflow.com/q/8288414/2943403 (php version dependent outcomes regarding code ambiguity)  For that matter, when I am echoing data, I always use commas for concatenation because it clarifies the script's action as "displaying" rather than concatenating while declaring -- which a dot must be used for.

Comment: We need more context. Where is this code placed exactly? Is `$this->item` really a category object? Does `$this->item->jcfields` actually contains the fields? Is `$child` a category object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had pieces of my code from https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/23675/13353, but this didn't help me.

And further today I found a solution on https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/23227.

The problem was, that i don't have the current category id. Now with this, it's working. Thank you @Sharky for your tip, what object is $child.

```
<?php
$category   = JRequest::getInt('id');
echo 'cat id is: '. $category;
$currentCatFields = FieldsHelper::getFields('com_content.categories', $this->category, true);
echo '<pre>',print_r($currentCatFields,1),'</pre>';

foreach ($currentCatFields as $field) : 
echo $field->label . ':' . $field->value; 
endforeach 
?>
```

Comment: You don't need to get category ID and assign it to `$category` (it's not the same as `$this->category`). You just needed to pass category object which you already had (`$this->category` instead of `$this->item`) to `FieldsHelper::getFields()`.

Comment: Also avoid using `JRequest`. It's been long deprecated and will not be available in Joomla 4.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Do I also get this work in index.php?

Comment: Category object is not available in template's `index.php` file. You'd have to retrieve it and its fields. See similar answer about articles https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/23050/12652.